# How should I rewrite this piece of code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

These functions ( * ) and ( ** ) are inside a `Backbone.View`, but I think the knowledge of Backbone is not needed to fix this problem.

As you can see from my comments in the code when:
1) I call the `getAvatar` function everything is ok,
2) when the getAvatar call the `setAvatar` something is broken

How should I fix the following problem?

---

( * )

```
    getAvatar: function ()
    {
        var creatorIds = this.getCreatorIds();
        console.log(creatorIds); // [1,2]  ******  here is ok *******

        for (var c = 0, l = creatorIds.length; c < l; c += 1) {
            if (typeof this.avatars[creatorIds[c]] === 'undefined') {
                this.userModel = new UserModel({id: creatorIds[c]});
                this.userModel.fetch();
                this.userModel.on('change', this.setAvatar, this);      
            }
        }
    },
```

---

( ** )

```
    setAvatar: function ()
    {       
        console.log(this.userModel.get('id')); // 2, 2  *********  it should be 1, 2  *******
        this.names[this.userModel.get('id')] = this.userModel.get('name');
        this.avatars[this.userModel.get('id')] = typeof this.userModel.get('avatar');
        this.render();
    },
```

---

(***)

```
initialize: function ()
{
     _.bindAll(this, 'getAvatar', 'setAvatar');
}
```

Comment: in `initialize`, are you binding the scope of either function? `_.bindAll(this)`, or something similar?

Comment: You are overwritting the value of this.userModel in the loop. You can provide `context` as a third parameter of `.on` and set the `this` in setAvatar to exact `UserModel` instance

Comment: @Darhazer I did try what you suggest but with the same result... I suppose the problem is about this.userModel . what do you think?

Comment: @rjz I did try what you suggest but with the same result... I suppose the problem is about this.userModel . what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like backbone.js has a third parameter for context for [on](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-on)

```
object.on(event, callback, [context])
```

Your code would be

```
getAvatar: function ()
{
    var creatorIds = this.getCreatorIds();
    console.log(creatorIds); // [1,2]  ******  here is ok *******

    for (var c = 0, l = creatorIds.length; c < l; c += 1) {
        if (typeof this.avatars[creatorIds[c]] === 'undefined') {
            this.userModel = new UserModel({id: creatorIds[c]});
            this.userModel.fetch();
            this.userModel.on('change', this.setAvatar, this );  //added this after the function.
        }
    }
},
```

or you could use a closure

```
getAvatar: function ()
{
    var that = this;  //variable to maintain scope
    var creatorIds = this.getCreatorIds();
    console.log(creatorIds); // [1,2]  ******  here is ok *******

    for (var c = 0, l = creatorIds.length; c < l; c += 1) {
        if (typeof this.avatars[creatorIds[c]] === 'undefined') {
            this.userModel = new UserModel({id: creatorIds[c]});
            this.userModel.fetch();
            this.userModel.on('change', function(){ that.setAvatar(); } );  //use a closure here with that variable that which is defined above.    
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: I did try both you suggested and I get the same problem... Anyway, I will try to make a jsfiddle.net to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I wuold assign -1 because as I said the problem is not the context but because I am assigning the same variable twice. anyway I have just 90 point and I cannot vote down.

Comment: @js999 If you are assigning the same variable twice, than make it an array. push the new entry to the end.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're assigning the same variable twice. In `getAvatar()`, you'll first set `this.userModel` to the UserModel with id == 1. Then on the next loop iteration, it will be assigned the UserModel with id == 2.

When the `setAvatar()` function is hit, it will look at `this.userModel` and only see the one value you set.  You should try not to use an instance variable to store the model.

Here is one way to fix it. There are probably easier ways to fix it, but it's hard to tell from the code sample given. I also added a few comments about some oddities in the code.

( * )

```
getAvatar: function ()
{
    var creatorIds = this.getCreatorIds();
    console.log(creatorIds); // [1,2]  ******  here is ok *******

    var self = this;

    for (var c = 0, l = creatorIds.length; c < l; c += 1) {
        if (typeof this.avatars[creatorIds[c]] === 'undefined') {
            var user = new UserModel({id: creatorIds[c]});

            //probably better to bind the handler first, in case fetch() completes synchronously from cache
            user.on('change', function(){
                console.log(user.get('id'));
                self.names[user.get('id')] = user.get('name');
                self.avatars[user.get('id')] = typeof user.get('avatar'); //are you sure you want typeof here?
                self.render(); //Note, this will get called a lot. Are you sure you want to do this?
            });   

            user.fetch();   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If that was the solution then you should mark this is as the correct answer.

Comment: I know, don't worr. Anyway +1 because you are right saying I am  assigning the same variable twice, but in your code there is a closure problem, I suppose.

Comment: Possibly, I did freehand it. You could also replace the `for()` loop with something like `_.each(creatorIds, function(c){ ... });`